# Typed arrays and union types

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typed-arrays

I work with typed arrays a lot and a lot of my functions really should be able to work with any sort of typed array (e.g., summing a `Uint8Array` or a `Float32Array`). Sometimes, I can get away with just a simple type union, but often I keep running into the same error.

A simple example:

```
type T1 = Uint8Array;
type T2 = Int8Array;
type T3 = Uint8Array | Int8Array;

// No problems here:
const f1 = (arr: T1) => arr.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value);
const f2 = (arr: T2) => arr.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value);

// Does not work:
const f3 = (arr: T3) => arr.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value);
```

The error on `f3` is:

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '
{
    (callbackfn: (previousValue: number, currentValue: number, currentIndex: number, array: Uint8Array) => number): number;
    (callbackfn: (previousValue: number, currentValue: number, currentIndex: number, array: Uint8Array) => number, initialValue: number): number;
    <U>(callbackfn: (previousValue: U, currentValue: number, currentIndex: number, array: Uint8Array) => U, initialValue: U): U;
} | {
    (callbackfn: (previousValue: number, currentValue: number, currentIndex: number, array: Int8Array) => number): number;
    (callbackfn: (previousValue: number, currentValue: number, currentIndex: number, array: Int8Array) => number, initialValue: number): number;
    <U>(callbackfn: (previousValue: U, currentValue: number, currentIndex: number, array: Int8Array) => U, initialValue: U): U; 
}' has no compatible call signatures.ts(2349)
```

According to the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

> If we have a value that has a union type, we can only access members that are common to all types in the union.

The way I'm using `reduce` here is common to all arrays, but I surmise the problem is the optional 4th argument (which for `Uint8Array.prototype.reduce` is a `Uint8Array` but for `Int8Array.prototype.reduce` is an `Int8Array`).

Is there a simple work-around for this? Or do I need to write a generics implementation for each of `map`, `reduce`, `filter`?

Comment: Well there is an ugly solution `(arr as Uint8Array).reduce((a, b) => a + b)`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has always been an issue in invoking unions of functions. Until recently the rule was that no invocation would be allowed at all, but since 3.3 ([PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29011)) invocation is allowed with some caveats. The big one you are hitting here is that if the constituents of the union both have generic signatures the call will still not be allowed. So for example on simple arrays one `forEach` can be called (no generic type parameters on it), while `reduce` can't be called (since both `reduce` from `string[]` and from `number[]` have a generic type parameter):

```
declare let o: string[] | number[];
o.forEach((e: number | string) => console.log(e)); // ok 
o.reduce((e: number | string, r: number | string) => e + ' ' + r) //err
```

This does mean having a union of array types is difficult to use and only allows invocation of a very small set of methods (most Array methods have generic type parameters).

This also applies to `Uint8Array` and `Int8Array` which while don't inherit array have most of the same methods.

There is no good solution here, the simplest work around is to assert the variable to one of the types and go with that (assuming you don't use the `array` callback parameter it should be ok)

```
const f3 = (arr: T3) => (arr as Uint8Array).reduce((sum, value, array /* no good inferred to Uint8Array */) => sum + value);
```

Or fall back to one of the functions you can invoke

```
const f4 = (arr: T3) => {
    let sum = 0;
    (arr as Uint8Array).forEach((val)=> sum + val)
}
```

Comment: But `forEach` does not have a generic type parameter. Edited the answer to be more clear

Comment: So it's not the type of the `array` parameter on the callback that's the problem. It's that both types have a generic type parameter, and the implementation in that PR stopped shy of trying to deal with that level of complexity. As it says in the PR, *"this seems like a good stopping point."* Huh.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah, that is it. IMO the common use case I have seen for this is exactly unions of arrays so the fact that weswigham stopped there is unfortunate (although I can see the mess merging generic methods with different constraints might be)

Comment: This is driving me a bit nuts. :-) I can't replicate it with other types: https://pastebin.com/JXnNFQiw (playground link is too large). Even if I copy the entire definition of `Int8Array` and `Uint8Array` from `lib.es6.d.ts` and rename them `FooArray` and `BarArray`, the OP's example works. But not with `Int8Array` and `Uint8Array`. o_O I also can't help but note that the OP's call doesn't match the overload of `reduce` with the generic type parameter, because it only provides one argument, which only matches the first overload of the three.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the issue is that your two types are structurally identical so the union actually collapses on inspection so there is no union of functions to cause the issue. The interfaces defined in `lib.d.ts` are structurally the same, but the parts added in `lib.es2015.symbol.wellknown.d.ts`  actually make the types incompatible (`interface Int8Array {
    readonly [Symbol.toStringTag]: "Int8Array";
}

interface Uint8Array {
    readonly [Symbol.toStringTag]: "UInt8Array";
}`)

Comment: Thank you. I figured there had to be a reason. :-) Sure enough, adding those makes it fail the same way. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is simple workaround. Declare interface with common method signature

```
type T3 = Uint8Array | Int8Array;

interface HasReduce {
    reduce(c: (p: number, n: number) => number): number; // common callback signture with 2 arguments
}

function someLogic(arr: HasReduce): number { 
    return arr.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value);
}

declare var v : T3;
someLogic(v); // OK
```

So you can declare HasMap, HasFilter and combine them.

Comment: No need to limit the callback to two parameters ([playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgzFAvFAqgSwHbABwEEBO+AhiFAD5QCSWehJA3AFCObAT4BmRAxtDOBAAmBYiADCAewC2UiRigBvRlBVR8QgK68AFNwBcUbWAMYNUgEbsANFAwmzl-DbT2L1qEQP9IwuuOmyGACUSAB8tg7sQa6OTAC+zBwaGNzAaHJQAM7SEAAyEgDmaNzaRIReAr6ikjJy0RFu+IpQyqrqwBr48mX4AHTqgloQ2tqZZjYAbkQANhoQIYjhY1JQANRQU7Pz8cyCENzTZdBTTRNQXnBM2VJ5hcXaE0H0UAD0L1AA8gDSQA)). I think this is what the OP was talking about wanting to avoid doing, though. It's not just `reduce`, there's `map`, `filter`, `copyWithin`, ...

Comment: Then there's the maintenance hazard of having to add new methods to the interface, rather than just being able to inherit edits to the typed array interfaces. (It may still be the only/best solution, though. I'm hoping not, but...)